# Java SSL Certificate Verification with a proxy

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have an Issue with the verification of a ssl certificate.
What I am trying to do, is sending some data from a java program to a server, which then stores that data.

The issue is, that the ssl certificate validation fails with the following exception:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed [...] unable to find valid certification path to...

I am able to resolve this issue, by adding the "end-user" certificate of the server to the truststore I am using.

The chain looks something like this:

```
Root Certificate 1
Intermediate Cert 11
Intermediate Certificate x
End-User Certificate
```

Something to note about this whole chain / process:
The communication is using the companies proxy, which replaces all the certificates, and creates its own chain.

So back to the issue:
By adding the end-user certificate everything runs fine. But only for a little while, before that certificate gets refreshed and the one I added is no longer valid. I have tried adding just the root certificate, just each intermediate certificate, adding all 3 certificates and also adding the certificate which would be used if the proxy does not replace the chain. But somehow the certificate cannot be validated.

Is there something I might be overlooking? Do I have to add something else to be able to validate the certificate?

Edit:
Maybe something to note:
I checked the chain, by using the browser and navigating to said server, and then checking the ssl certificates.

Comment: If I understand correctly then the proxy provides its own certificates, meaning the Root Certificate is not one of the well-known CAs but some "private" certificate (scoped to whoever uses the proxy, right?). In that case you simply need to add that proxy CA to the list of known CAs (or replace the list if you *only* want to deal with that CA). But be aware that this means that whoever controls that CA can spoof certificates for *any* domain.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes the Root CA is a privately issued certificate by the company. And I have added that one to the truststore already. But the program is still unable to validate the certificate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to be an issue with the certificates provided by the company that replaced the certificate chain.

For some reason the chain was not completed, and I had to add all certificates in the chain to the truststore to make it work.